# Navigation drifting in wind

Tags: shortest-path

I have an interesting problem that I cannot immediately solve in a way that I believe will work:

A helium balloon is flying, drifting with the wind. The wind directions and speeds are different at different altitudes; I can get data for each integral degree of latitude and longitude, with about 15 different values for different altitudes. We can just model the airspace of a 4D array of wind directions and speeds, where the 4th dimension is time (3hr resolution).

Now I want to find:

- Is it feasible to fly the balloon from A to B in the winds, by changing altitude some places underway?
- What is the minimum cost? There are 2 different costs, flight time and rapid altitude changes (which require throwing limited resources of ballast or gas overboard)

A naive solution is just to make a graph with one vertex for each cube and edges from each cube to the downwind cube, and then use Dijkstra. But this will make the flight a straight N/S/E/W line between cube centres, which it isn't.

OK, then I could divide each cube into a number of sub-cubes and increase resolution that way (instead of stepping between neighboring cubes, make edges between cubes and those n minutes of flight downwind, skipping through the intermediaries). That would get me a huge data set.

Any better ideas (out of the Dijkstra box maybe?)

(I have tried s simple solution, just choosing an altitude to stay as close to the direct line to the destination as I can. That works pretty well sometimes, but I have no knowledge whether it is optimal in time and resource consumption. And often the balloon gets stuck in a place with headwinds at all altitudes)